# How to exit from Javascript processing after DWR-based validation

Tags: java, javascript, ajax, dwr

I'm relatively new to Javascript and new to Ajax and DWR - I suspect this is a Javascript question rather than Ajax/DWR, but here goes:

I'm writing Javascript that uses DWR to call a remote Java method to validate some data entered in the browser. If the validation fails (the Java method returns an error message (non-empty string), I want to show an error message to the user and do no more Javascript processing. If the validation succeeds (empty string returned by the Java method) I want to continue in my Javascript to process the user's input.

What I'm finding is that on a validation error, the error message is shown, but the Javascript processing does not stop, it continues as if the validation succeeded. So my question is how do I end the Javascript processing when the validation fails ('A:' in the code below).

This is a mix of Javascript and pseudocode but it should illustrate what I'm doing.

Thanks for any help,

Steve

```
MyRemoteService.validateData(myData, {
    callback:function(str) { 
        if (str) {
        // A: show an error message
            return;
        }                           
    }
    });


// pseudocode - this is what I want to happen:

if (validation error)
    //    don't do anything else
}

// Data was valid  - continue to do stuff
```

Comment: Have you tried simply `return false;`? Hard to tell without seeing the actual javascript.

Answer (score 3):

Making the DWR call synchronous solves the issue:

```
MyRemoteService.validateData(myData, {
   async: false,
   callback:function(str) { 
        if (str) {
        // A: show an error message
            return;
        }                           
    }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

As far i can understand your post,

You want to execute some java script code, only after you get the result from backend either if its success or error message!(Am i right or missing something)

If thats the case, write your javascript code with in the dwr call back function. So, they will get called only after the result comes from the back end.